# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type T

Tags: java, generics

```
public class BlockingQueue<T> { 
    public static List<T> queue =new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

I am getting error while trying to create generic `Arraylist`?

Comment: Do you understand what static means? If so, please explain the reason for using it here.

Comment: For completeness, the correct syntax for what you are trying to do is `public static <T> List<T> queue = new ArrayList<T>;`, but semantically it is highly unlikely that you really want a static field here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That makes sense. Think about what the `T` means - you are defining a class where each **instance** specifies its generic concrete type.

However **static members belong to the class** and not a specific instance. when you define a static member in it, that depends on such `T` what will it be? Static has no instance - so what `T`.

If you want the `queue` to be a member of the instance, and depend on `T` just remove the `static`:

```
public class BlockingQueue<T> {
    public List<T> queue = new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `T` parameterized type for a class is associated to the instance of the class and not to the class itself but `static` is a class and not an instance modifier.
So the compiler doesn't accept that you reference `T` from a static field/method.

Defining a generic class underlies taking advantage of the generic specified by the instance.
So removing the static `modifier` makes more sense :

```
public class BlockingQueue<T> {

   public List<T> queue = new ArrayList<T>();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error i was trying to create static reference,I missed that .Working code below .Thanks @chrylis

```
public class BlockingQueue<T> {
    public List<T> queue =new ArrayList<T>();
}
```